# Floor constraint stop the bone visually but keep updating it's position

Tags: animation, constraints

There's this weird behavior after I added a floor constraint. While it worked well visually, it didn't in the background. Even though the it blocked the bone from going beyond the plane, the mouse movement still add to it z position as if it wasn't blocked. I added the plane just to help me create animation, so once I removed it, as expected the animation is all over the place.

Is there an alternative to floor constraint, or am I doing something wrong. Thank you.

Comment: That's normal, but you should be able to check the Affect Transform checkbox in the constraint modifier to stop that happening.

Comment: I don't see it anywhere in the constraint panel, in blender 2.9.

Comment: Ah apologies. It was late at night here and I was looking at the Limit Location and Rotation constraint settings. :^(

Comment: No problem, though, you gave me the idea of using limit location constraint, but it has the same problem and affect transform doesn't change anything.

Comment: In that case I'm not really sure what you're asking. I assumed you were talking about turning off the effect detailed [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6nmT123wVe4&t=1127s) at 30:35 in this simple rigging tutorial by Joey Carlino.

Comment: That's exactly it, it was just my carelessness. I looked at transform and saw numbers keep changing and thought it was the axis I specified. Thank you.

Comment: Just an illusion then! :^)